# Javascript Json & AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am working on javascript & Json & Ajax but i have few question in my mind that json file can work without localhost ? and secondly about ajax can we use ajax with json on locally our hard disk not at localhost?

Comment: Hi! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some inspiration on how to improve your question. From reading it just now I have no Idea what you're aiming at here.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a method for requesting files via HTTP. You can only use Ajax to request files on the same server, because of the Same-Origin-Policy (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy). So no, if your server is on localhost, you have to request the files on localhost. You cannot access the local file system. You can upload your files though, and then request them using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a web server then there is nowhere for the the AJAX request to be sent. AJAX needs the web server to communicate with in order for it to be able to retrieve any data.

Without using a web server you are viewing a file at address "`file://...some path.../filename.html`". In this scenario sending an AJAX request to another domain is not allowed because of cross site scripting.

Comment: Ok and what about json file like (sample.json) can we access the data of this file withour using web server ? i have tried in my live search app so it has not work ! but at the other side in another small app i have tried to get access my json file on hard drive not a web server so its works! that's why i am confused that somewhere work somewhere don't so kindly get me out this confusion ?

Comment: You can load the JSON file using the File API - it's only implemented in Chrome and Firefox. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API